# Repeating the query for Link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have a link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Go", all_integrations_path({q: Report.last.rules }) %>
```

Where Report.last.rules:

```
{"bio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any"=>["mcmaster", "entrepreneur"], "facebook_username_not_eq"=>"null"}
```

This works great when there isn't an array but when there is, I end up getting duplicated "bio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any"

I get repeats:

```
<a href="/integrations/all?q%5Bbio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=mcmaster&amp;q%5Bbio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any%5D%5B%5D=garden">Go</a>
```

How can I change it such that it does a `+` rather than duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create the query parameter to whatever value you want before passing to the url helper. Something like this:

```
query = Report.last.rules['bio_or_topics_or_title_or_company_cont_any']
query = query.join("+") if query

link_to "Go", all_integrations_path(q: query)
```

Comment: any way to do all this in one line? And rules is a hash which has other keys I want to use too so cannot just put query

Comment: this just an example. Do whatever you need with results before passing them through. The point is to transform Report.last.rules result to an object of your liking before passing it to url helper

Comment: since you you are using this in views, you should create helper method that hides all this logic from the view. This will allow to have a one-liner in views.  link_to "go", path(q: transformed_results) where transformed_results could be your helper method